# Execute Code on Completion of Multiple setInterval Functions

Tags: javascript, html, multithreading, css, css-animations

Hello Everyone and thank you in advance for your time!

I am working on a site involving simultaneous CSS3 animations. I am using setInterval() calls to run the animations. I am looking for the best way to call a function after the animations finish.

The code below is just a generic sample to explain my question. When you press the start button, three setInterval() functions are called. One animates translation, one animates scaling, and the last animates rotation. The essence of my question is, how can I run some code - for the sake of argument let's say console.log("We Did IT!"); - when the last clearInterval() is called.

I can imagine a boolean network tracking which animations have finished and calling the code when all the flags are thrown, but I was hoping there was a more elegant solution to be found here.

Thanks again!

```js
//Global Variable Declarations
var adc = adc || {};
adc.tWrap = document.createElement('div');
adc.sWrap = document.createElement('div');
adc.rWrap = document.createElement('div');
adc.btn = document.createElement('button');

//Style Objects, Append to Body, Apply Listeners
adc.init = function() {
  adc.setDiv(adc.tWrap, "transform wrap", 22, 22, 200, 200, 1, "");
  adc.setDiv(adc.sWrap, "scale wrap", 22, 22, 150, 150, 2, "", "");
  adc.setDiv(adc.rWrap, "rotate wrap", 22, 22, 100, 100, 3, "yellow");

  adc.setBtn(adc.btn, "start btn", 25, 25, 50, 50, "Start");
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
  body[0].appendChild(adc.tWrap);
  adc.tWrap.appendChild(adc.sWrap);
  adc.sWrap.appendChild(adc.rWrap);
  adc.rWrap.appendChild(adc.btn);

  adc.btn.addEventListener('click', adc.click, true);
}
adc.setDiv = function(a, id, T, L, H, W, z, bg) {
  a.id = id;
  a.style.position = 'absolute';
  a.style.top = T + "px";
  a.style.left = L + "px";
  a.style.height = H + "px";
  a.style.width = W + "px";
  a.style.zIndex = z;
  a.style.borderWidth = "3px";
  a.style.borderStyle = "solid";
  a.style.backgroundColor = bg;
}
adc.setBtn = function(a, id, T, L, H, W, txt) {
  a.id = id;
  a.type = "button";
  a.textContent = txt;
  a.style.position = 'absolute';
  a.style.top = T + "px";
  a.style.left = L + "px";
  a.style.height = H + "px";
  a.style.width = W + "px";
}

//Event Listener
adc.click = function() {
  if (!adc.animate.runLock()) {
    adc.animate.trans.start();
    adc.animate.scale.start();
    adc.animate.rotate.start();
  }
}

//Animation Routines (setInterval calls)
adc.animate = {
  runLock: function() {
    if (adc.animate.trans.run == 0 && adc.animate.scale.run == 0 && adc.animate.rotate.run == 0) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  },
  trans: {
    run: 0,
    count: 0,
    flag: false,
    start: function() {
      this.run = setInterval(function() {
        adc.animate.trans.EXE()
      }, 10);
    },
    stop: function() {
      clearInterval(this.run);
      this.run = this.count = 0;
      this.flag = false;
    },
    EXE: function() {
      if (!this.flag) {
        this.count += 0.5;
      } else {
        this.count -= 0.5;
      }
      if (this.count >= 45) {
        this.flag = true;
      }
      adc.tWrap.style.transform = "translateX(" + this.count + "px)";
      if (this.count <= 0) {
        this.stop();
      }
    }
  },
  scale: {
    run: 0,
    count: 1,
    flag: false,
    start: function() {
      this.run = setInterval(function() {
        adc.animate.scale.EXE()
      }, 10);
    },
    stop: function() {
      clearInterval(this.run);
      this.run = 0;
      this.count = 1;
      this.flag = false;
    },
    EXE: function() {
      if (!this.flag) {
        this.count += 0.01;
      } else {
        this.count -= 0.01;
      }
      if (this.count >= 1.9) {
        this.flag = true;
      }
      adc.sWrap.style.transform = "scale(" + this.count + ")";
      if (this.count <= 1) {
        this.stop();
      }
    }
  },
  rotate: {
    run: 0,
    count: 0,
    flag: false,
    start: function() {
      this.run = setInterval(function() {
        adc.animate.rotate.EXE()
      }, 10);
    },
    stop: function() {
      clearInterval(this.run);
      this.run = this.count = 0;
      this.flag = false;
    },
    EXE: function() {
      if (!this.flag) {
        this.count++;
      } else {
        this.count--;
      }
      if (this.count >= 90) {
        this.flag = true;
      }
      adc.rWrap.style.transform = "rotate(" + this.count + "deg)";
      if (this.count <= 0) {
        this.stop();
      }
    }
  }
}

//Initialization Call
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  adc.init();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo-Dash has a convenient function called [`_.after`](https://lodash.com/docs#after) which executes a given function after a certain number of calls. For example, the following function only executes after all the timeouts have been completed.

```js
var finish = _.after(5, function () {
  console.log('All functions completed!');
});

setTimeout(function () { console.log('A'); finish(); },  500);
setTimeout(function () { console.log('B'); finish(); }, 1000);
setTimeout(function () { console.log('C'); finish(); }, 1500);
setTimeout(function () { console.log('D'); finish(); }, 2000);
setTimeout(function () { console.log('E'); finish(); }, 2500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If you don't want to include Lo-Dash, you can implement `_.after` yourself fairly easily:

```
function callAfter(n, func) {
  var i = 0;
  return function () {
    if (i < n) { i++; }
    else { return func(); }
  };
}
```